# How to expose the variables in an entry module as global variables with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

i am hoping for some webpack option (or loader) like `bare` in `coffee` which removes the top-level function wrapper and expose the variables for convenience in debugging.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use [source maps](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) for convenience in debugging?

Comment: i use source maps but i really want to be able to play/inspect/experiment with variables defined in the entry script in chrome devtool during development. I basically want to execute entry script at global context. the closest thing i found is [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader)

Comment: Hmm, not sure how if there is a way to do what you want in webpack. Maybe you could use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) and debug by exporting the variables that you would like to inspect.

Comment: right, need to add `module.exports`. that is helpful. aha, i think i figured it out! `script-loader` can solve this but you need to turn off strict mode.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `script-loader` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) evaluates the required module in the global context. Essentially it generates `eval(source)` in the global context in the output bundled javascript file. Beware to avoid setting `use strict` otherwise the eval would create its own scope (instead of using the global context).